# Getting a list of entity names and the associated properties

Tags: json, ravendb

I'm dynamically creating some collections in my database. I instantiate `ExpandoObjects` and manually set the entity name. This works fine.

Now I need to get a list of entities, with the associated properties (which *should* be the same for all the documents in the collection, but not *necessarily*)

The result should be a list of:

```
class Collection
{
    string Name;
    string[] Properties;
}
```

Now, I know I can create an index that references `["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]`, and since JSON objects (or `RavenJObjects`, or `ExpandoObjects`) are dictionaries, I thought I would be able to retrieve `doc.Keys` **(I think this is what doesn't work)**

This is my work in progress, which does not work (the `Properties` array contains one `null` per document in the collection)

Map:

```
from doc in docs
let Name = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]
where Name.StartsWith("External_")
select new { Name, Properties = doc.Keys }
```

Reduce:

```
from result in results
group result by result.Name into r
select new { Name = r.Key, Properties = r.Select(x => x.Properties).Distinct() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was on the right track. I finally got it.

Map:

```
from doc in docs
let Name = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]
where Name.StartsWith("External_")
from property in doc
select new { Name, Properties = new[] { property.Key } }
```

Reduce:

```
from result in results
group result by result.Name into r
select new { Name = r.Key, Properties = r.SelectMany(x => x.Properties).Distinct() }
```